# Travelling through a worm hole

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, wormholes, exotic-matter

In every documentary I've seen about worm holes, I have noticed that they usually say that according to the General Theory of Relativity, there could exist worm holes called traversable wormholes; these are stable worm holes and travelling through them is possible. In that case they can be used to travel in time, and Inter-Universe travel may also be possible. One can also find some of the above statements [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole).

Now my questions are the following:

1. Is travelling through a worm hole really possible (if we can find a stable worm hole)?

   The reason for the question is: according to the same general theory of relativity which gives them the traversable worm whole with exotic matter, worm holes have a similar metric to black holes. As we go close to a black hole the gravitational pull at one point of our body (or a spaceship or probe's body) is different from the gravitational pull at some other point of our body (or a spaceship or probe's body) which will lead to a severe stress and our body (or a spaceship or probe's body) will be broken into pieces. This should also be the case for a worm hole, I guess. Worm holes are a particular kind of space-time distortion or a field of gravitation, similarly to black holes, so can any man-made instrument or craft survive the trip through a region of severely in-homogeneous gravitational field?

If the answer of Q1. is "no", then I would also like to know

2. i. Why is such a thing shown in scientific documentaries narrated by world-widely popular scientists?
   ii. Are those documentaries not misleading their audiences?

I also have a separate question,

3. If there is a worm hole, will it not attract nearby objects? or don't worm holes exert gravitational attraction?

Answer (score -5):

I can only answer with opinion rather than facts, but for what it's worth:

*Is travelling through a worm hole really possible (if we can find one stable worm hole)?*

No. Wormholes are science fiction. So is time travel. See [A World without Time: The Forgotten Legacy of Godel and Einstein](http://www.amazon.co.uk/World-without-Time-Forgotten-Einstein/dp/0465092942). A clock doesn't literally clock up the flow of time like some cosmic gas meter. It features some kind of regular cyclical motion, such as a pendulum or an oscillating crystal, which it effectively counts, showing you a cumulative result called "the time". This is just a measure of motion, and you can't travel through a measure of motion. Wormholes permit time travel, so they're science fiction too. Despite what you saw in [Interstellar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film)).

*Can any man-made instrument or craft survive the trip through a region of severely in-homogeneous gravitational field?*

There's a problem with this question, in that a gravitational field is a region of inhomogeneous space. See Einstein talking about it in his 1920 [Leyden Address](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Extras/Einstein_ether.html), and [this paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/0256-307X/25/5/014). But I'll presume the question is *can a craft survive a trip through a severe gravitational field*, to which I'll say yes. But it isn't some back-to-the-future wormhole.

*Why is such thing shown in some scientific documentaries narrated by some world widely popular scientists?*

Because some of those "popular scientists" are more interested in promoting themselves than serious science, and because the science-fiction stuff attracts attention. Woo sells. People lap it up.

*Isn't showing such thing misleading the audience?*

Yep.

*If there is a worm hole will not it attract the nearby objects or isn't worm hole exert gravitational attraction?*

Notwithstanding my comments above, any concentration of energy will cause gravity, and we know of nothing which consists of negative energy.

Comment: This fails to really address the question, and it ignores the existence of GR solutions with closed timelike curves.

Comment: There are theories of wormholes that do not violate known laws of physics (often they come with other solutions that *do* violate laws, i.e. white holes and the 2nd law of thermodynamics) so I think this answer is perhaps a bit misleading. Also, FYI there are theories of gravity that do admit 'repulsive' gravity, for example Domain walls.